# I can't get an object name by requested user with drf serializer and CreateAPIView

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have:
 object1 with OneToOneField with user,
 object2 with ForeignKeys to user and object1.

in the serializer, I want to retrieve the name of object1 and make it as a default name in object2.
createAPIView prohibit get operation while I can use hiddenfield with currentDefaultUser.
how can I get the user id and use it to retrieve the object1?
should i use retreive and create mixins?

## models

```
class Object1(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object1_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)

class Object2(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object2_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
```

## serializers

```
class Object_2_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Object2
        fields = ('user', 'object1_name', 'object2_name',)
```

## views

```
class object_2_CreateView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                     mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     ):
    queryset = Object2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Object_2_Serializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    lookup_field = 'object1_name'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I want to get object1_name.

Comment: Show your models,serializer and views

Comment: I updated my question, thanks.